# python subprocess to open excel file

Tags: python, excel, subprocess

The goal is to open a particular excel file using a python shell subprocess. The code cannot be more simple yet I cannot figure out what is wrong:

```
import subprocess
arg1 = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE"
arg2 = "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\test.xlsm"
p = subprocess.Popen(["start", arg1, arg2], shell=False)
```

The command works perfectly directly on the shell but when done through subprocess throws the following error:
`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

I have also tried the below which works equally fine directly on the shell but the behavior is different:
`p = subprocess.Popen([arg1, arg2], shell=False)`

The following failed assertion pops up from Excel:
[snapshopt error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yfbh.png)

My next try was:

```
import os
os.system("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\test.xlsm")
```

Which replicates the same assertion error as above plus returns a code 3 which based on 
[System Error Codes (0-499)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-)
is a path not found.

Again same path works on shell, at this stage I run out of ideas, any help?

Comment: Isnt `start` as shell command ? So you should probably use `shell=True`

Comment: yep shell true throws the assertion error from excel

Answer (score 3):

[os.startfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) is actually a better way to do it. As specified in the documentation -

> os.startfile(path[, operation])
>
> Start a file with its associated application.
>
> When operation is not specified or 'open', this acts like
>   double-clicking the file in Windows Explorer, or giving the file name
>   as an argument to the start command from the interactive command
>   shell: the file is opened with whatever application (if any) its
>   extension is associated.
>
> When another operation is given, it must be a “command verb” that
>   specifies what should be done with the file. Common verbs documented
>   by Microsoft are 'print' and 'edit' (to be used on files) as well as
>   'explore' and 'find' (to be used on directories)

You can just do the following -

```
import os

os.startfile("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\test.xlsm")
```

Comment: Thanks for that but this gives the same assertion error as above.